# sabre car new bookAPI EnhancedVehBookRQ

Tags: soap, sabre

I tried to call EnhancedVehBookRQ API with CERT ENV
This is my request and response

**REQUEST:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" >
        <soapenv:Header>
            <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
                <BinarySecurityToken>
                token
                </BinarySecurityToken>
            </Security>
            <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
                <From>
                    <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">from</PartyId>
                </From>
                <To>
                    <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">to</PartyId>
                </To>
                <CPAId>hiddendata
                </CPAId>
                <ConversationId>hiddendata</ConversationId>
                <Action>EnhancedVehBookRQ</Action>
                <MessageData>
                    <MessageId>1001</MessageId>
                    <Timestamp>2021-08-18T10:00:01</Timestamp>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <TimeToLive>2021-08-19T10:00:01</TimeToLive>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <Timeout>0</Timeout>
                </MessageData>
            </MessageHeader>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <EnhancedVehBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/enhanced/veh/book/v1" version="1.0.0">
                <VehBook>
                    <BookingInfo >
                        <BookingKey>23accd05-4770-4d1c-a286-ab0e6f360fc5
                    </BookingKey>
                    </BookingInfo>
                    <Customer NameNumber="1.1">
                        <Address>
                            <CityName>DALLAS</CityName>
                            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                            <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
                            <StateCountyProv StateCode="TX" />
                            <StreetNmbr>1234 TEST ADDRESS</StreetNmbr>
                        </Address>
                    </Customer>
                    <RentalPaymentPrefs>
                        <GuaranteePrepaid Type="GUARANTEE">
                            <PaymentCard>
                                <CardCode>DC</CardCode>
                                <CardNumber>311234567685619</CardNumber>
                                <ExpiryMonth>12</ExpiryMonth>
                                <ExpiryYear>2022</ExpiryYear>
                                <FullCardHolderName>
                                    <LastName>Monster</LastName>
                                </FullCardHolderName>
                            </PaymentCard>
                        </GuaranteePrepaid>
                    </RentalPaymentPrefs>
                    <VehRentalCore Quantity="1" />
                </VehBook>
            </EnhancedVehBookRQ>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I could not move ahead with car booking, getting errors like this

```
<Message code="ERR.SP.INTERNAL_ERROR">TravelItineraryReadRQ: After maximum retry count it was not possible to successfully execute target service</Message>
```

Can anybody please confirm whether SOAP requst is proper or not or I am missing something from my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, before running **EnhancedVehBookRQ** API you need to run **PassengerDetailsRQ** with TravelIntinerary details in it. On the success of this API use the response details for the request of this API and then run it